# mySQL query to return last record for each table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQl db (name "stocks") with 50 tables, each tables with

id, symbol, date, time, open, high, low, close, volume as columns (9 columns).

I would like to know what is the last record for each table, ordered for date then time.

Should I have to ORDER BY all data for each table or there is a better way to just know last record?

I am asking help for a query that just return only last record for each table in db.

Thanks

PS For last record I mean most recent as Date then Time

Comment: Why aren't you using `DATETIME datetime` instead of `DATE date, TIME time`?

Comment: Oh it is just my preference to have separate columns.

Comment: It's my personal opinion and it's nothing wrong on how you do have it but I'd rather use `DATETIME`, you can easily use `TIME( datetime)` or `DATE( datetime)` to get those information separately, and on the other hand sorting data based on time would be easier and perhaps faster.

Comment: Thank you very much Vyktor for your comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two options how to do that:

```sql
-- I would use this only if you need more than one records
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;

-- Way to go:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table) LIMIT 1;
```

Don't forget to add index on `date`. If it's possible you add lot's of records at the same time you will have to add:

```sql
ORDER BY id DESC -- In case that date is highest for records for last records
ORDER BY time DESC -- Every other case
```

To the end of query

Comment: You'd probably want to check `time` as well as `date`, in case there are multiple records with the same value and they are all `max(date)`. Of course, if there are many inserts happening at the same time, there could be collisions on `time` as well, unless `time` has microsecond (or better) precision.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner somehow I assumed that he would be using `DATETIME` in case of many records per day... But you're right, I've added handling of records (id seems most reliable quantifier on "one table query", assuming it's create data, heh).

Comment: `ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC` is probably what the OP wants (see his edit).

Answer (score 7):

I am going to make the assumption that the record with the largest ID is the "last" (assuming strictly increasing sequential IDs that are unique within a table). If you have a better definition of "last" that could make a difference.

To get one "last" record, you could do:

```
Select * from table_1 where id = (select max(id) from table_1);
```

To get the results of all 50 tables into a single result set, you could do:

```
Select * from table_1 where id = (select max(id) from table_1)
union
Select * from table_2 where id = (select max(id) from table_2)
union
Select * from table_3 where id = (select max(id) from table_3)
union...
```

---

A MySQL-specific solution could be

```
Select * from table_1 order by id desc limit 1
union
Select * from table_2 order by id desc limit 1
union
Select * from table_3 order by id desc limit 1
union...
```

---

Based on your edit (where you actually define what you mean by "last"):

```
Select * from table_1 order by date desc, time desc, id desc limit 1
union
Select * from table_2 order by date desc, time desc, id desc limit 1
union
Select * from table_3 order by date desc, time desc, id desc limit 1
union...
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` gives same result in MySQL.

Comment: @ypercube: True, though since I don't have an instance of MySQL to test on, this solution is probably the most generic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it without sorting the table:

```
select * from tab1
 where time = (select max(time)
                 from tab1
                where date = (select max(date) from tab1))
   and date = (select max(date) from tab1)
```

It should be very fast, like, O(c), provided that both columns are indexed, otherwise the time will simply be O(n)